# Remove Entity Key from webapi in mvc 4

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my code trying to do webapi in dotnet

```
    Public Function [Get]() As IEnumerable(Of user_data)
    Dim db As New databaseusersEntities
    Dim avg_users = (From p In db.user_data
              Select p.FullName).ToList()
    Return db.user_data.ToList()
    'Return avg_users.ToList()  --- this one doesn't work
    End Function
```

I wanted to avoid getting the "Entity Key" from the json data and just the FullName, I used the POCO/DTO to prevent but getting the error

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1"

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of the method to string

```
Public Function [Get]() As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Dim db As New databaseusersEntities
    Dim avg_users = (From p In db.user_data
              Select p.FullName).ToList()
    Return avg_users.ToList()
End Function
```